# Event Propagation in flex

Tags: apache-flex

Why we need to use event Propagation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're asking. But assuming your question regards how to stop events from propagating, you can manipulate event propagation in three ways:

```
event.preventDefault()
```

and

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

and

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation()
```

I would recommend reading about the Event class and its methods at http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/index.html

Comment: You're a real sport for answering this. :)